# NAT traversal of VPN/proxy server in home network with no access to the router

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, nat

[image: initial setup]

I want to setup a VPN (or proxy) server on my workstation located outside my permanent residence and behind NAT. I need to use workstation's network IP. The problem is I don't have physical nor admin access to the router, so I cannot setup NAT traversal accordingly. Is there any non-corporate simple-to-use software/service that would allow me to bypass NAT?

I thought of TeamViewer example. As far as I know TeamViewer uses 3-way communication using their server-side in order to connect machines and bypass NAT. Are there any services out there providing similar access but for VPN functionality? Or how do you configure such server by yourself, so a remote VPN server behind NAT could ping it and therefore allow other machine to establish VPN connection? Or do you know of any other solutions that would solve this problem? Appreciate for any recommendations in advance.

[image: possible solutin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main functionality that you will want to look for in choosing a VPN solution is 'UDP hole-punching'. It works by coordinating (either manually or with a registry) the IP address, source and destination port of both ends of the VPN tunnel.

Assuming the firewalls are stateful, when a peer sends out a packet to the other peer, it temporarily opens a hole (source port) in the upstream firewall designed for return traffic. If the other peer targets this hole (destination port) with its VPN negotiation packets (and vice versa), they can establish a tunnel with only ever using outbound permissions, which are typically less restrictive.

A quick search for a VPN program with UDP hole-punching turned up Campagnol VPN on sourceforge. On cursory inspection, I believe this would fit your needs, though you would need to use an external server for registry. I'm sure there's other ones as well.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try. At least, now I know how its properly called.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there is a quick out-of-the-box solution for Windows - [Hamachi VPN](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)

Free version allows you to connect only up to 5 clients, which is enough for the described problem. But also free version is restricted to run in app mode only (in contrast to service mode), meaning you have to launch Hamachi client and log in to [LogmeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/central/) account manually after each system reboot.